# Receiving SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER when Attempting To Access Google Analytics

Tags: security, security-certificate

Whenever I attempt to access Google Analyics, I receive an "Insecure Connection" message.

In more detail:

```
analytics.google.com uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. The certificate is not valid for the name analytics.google.com. 
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

and

```
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/

Peer’s Certificate issuer is not recognized.

HTTP Strict Transport Security: false
HTTP Public Key Pinning: true

Certificate chain:
```

While I use FireFox as my primary browser, I also received the error in Chrome. I suspect the underlying issue may relate to an antivirus program I had installed (BitDefender), but I cannot be certain. I have since uninstalled BitDefender.

Any advice on how to rectify this issue would be appreciated. I am running Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here.  GA works fine for me.    To diagnose this issue we'd need more information such as the certificate chain that you omitted.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I actually did not admit any of the information I could retrieve about the chian. When I clicked the  SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER in FireFox, that is exactly what is displayed. I am presuming the chain is broken, but why and how to fix it I do not know. Thanks.

Comment: Can you get more information about the issuer of the certificate out of Chrome?   There isn't a lot to work with there.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Unfortunately, I am not sure how I would access that in Chrome. When I click "Advanced" I only received a message. `analytics.google.com normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Google Chrome tried to connect to analytics.google.com this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be analytics.google.com, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged..`

Comment: It looks like this is a question about configuring your computer rather than about running your website.   I'd move it to Super User, but it looks like somebody already asked the question there: https://superuser.com/questions/1168574/mozilla-error-sec-error-unknown-issuer

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I referenced the question you linked to, and it did not resolve the issue. However, I will try opening a new one on SuperUser. Thanks.

Comment: It also links to this which might be worth a try: [Reset messed up certificate data in Firefox and Thunderbird?](https://superuser.com/questions/344767/reset-messed-up-certificate-data-in-firefox-and-thunderbird)